# VS Code does not recognize Python interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Status bar on VS Code indicates Python 3.7.3 64-bit with path to Continuum's Anaconda distribution. Code fails on first line because it cannot import numpy.

Why is this so hard? I struggle each time I need to configure VScode with a python interpreter on a new machine, typically 3-4 hours each time get it to debug Python.

Comment: don't rely on the default, click on the lower left status bar and select the Python interpreter you want

Comment: First thing I did and it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it after your comments. So I install the current version of `Visual Studio Code` and Anaconda for `Python 3.7` (both as a non administrator user for Windows and add `Anaconda` to `path`).

My `settings.json` looks like this

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python.exe"
}
```

and `Visual Studio Code` is recognizing `Anaconda` instantly and I can use it without problems.

So maybe you should try to reinstall all packages. It definitely works together.

Comment: Python interpreter may be found. But there is a module import error. Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: This is not a problem with the interpreter. This is a problem with your environment, because one dependency isn´t installed correctly.

Comment: I think the problem is actually with the MS python distribution - ms-python. I can import modules if I open a Python terminal from Anaconda but cannot import modules from ms-python. Any idea why? I

Comment: I can open and run the code in Spyder without any issue - so it must be VScode. And the settings.json update does not help.

Comment: The output is confusing me - the console reports ''python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.' but the exception handler returns "Exception has occurred: ImportError DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." So VScode reports it cannot find python and at the same time has an error importing modules. Does VScode just not work with Anaconda?

Comment: Kampi - thanks but still does not seem to fix the issue. I installed PyCharm and it runs fine with both the Anaconda distribution and my own libraries, so it is definitely something with VScode.

Comment: I am not getting some error on 'conda activate base'. I just do not understand how VScode works.